# Mongo aggregation query to calculate multiple computed values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the below documents.

```
{
    _id: 1,
    ExpirationDate: ISODate("2017-05-02T09:29:46.006+0000")
}
{
    _id: 2,
    ExpirationDate: ISODate("2017-05-12T09:29:46.006+0000")
}
{
    _id: 3,
    ExpirationDate: ISODate("2017-05-23T09:29:46.006+0000")
}
```

How can I use aggregation pipleline to compute the following output?

```
{
    "NumberOfSubscriptionExpiringToday": 12,
    "NumberOfSubscriptionExpiringWithInAWeek": 4
}
```

I am looking to accomplish this with just one query instead of two. Here is what I have so far...

```
.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: {
            "ExpirationDate": {
                $gte: ISODate("2017-05-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                $lte: ISODate("2017-05-03T00:00:00.000+0000")
            }
        }
    },
    {  
        $project: {
            _id: 1
        }
    },
    { 
        $count: "ExpiringToday"
    }
]);


.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: {
            "ExpirationDate": {
                $gte: ISODate("2017-05-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                $lte: ISODate("2017-05-08T00:00:00.000+0000")
            }
        }
    },
    {  
        $project: {
            _id: 1
        }
    },
    { 
        $count: "ExpiringInSevenDays"
    }
]);
```

Comment: Why are you selecting only one day range? What is purpose of selecting only _id field? And you don't have ExpiringToday field, especially after selecing only _id

Comment: I could start with seven day range and then pass it through another $match stage to get one day range and project it. Would I have to use $addToFields to compute one day and seven day range?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Updated my question. How do I combine two queries into one?

Comment: You don't have any working queries here. Check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in single aggregation query with [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to check if each document expiration date falls into `[today, tomorrow)` range, or in `[tomorrow, weekAfterToday)` range:

```
var today = ISODate("2017-05-04T00:00:00.000");
var tomorrow = ISODate("2017-05-05T00:00:00.000");
var weekAfterToday = ISODate("2017-05-11T00:00:00.000");

db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "ExpirationDate": { $gte: today, $lt: weekAfterToday }}},
  {
      $project: {
        ExpiringToday: {
           $cond: {
               if: {
                   $and: [
                      {$gte: ["$ExpirationDate",today]},
                      {$lt:["$ExpirationDate",tomorrow]}
                   ]
               }, then: 1, else: 0
           }
        },
        ExpiringInAWeek: {
            $cond: { if: {$gte: ["$ExpirationDate",tomorrow]}, then: 1, else: 0 }
        }
      }
  },
  { $group: {
       _id: 1,
       NumberOfSubscriptionExpiringToday: {$sum: "$ExpiringToday" },
       NumberOfSubscriptionExpiringWithInAWeek: {$sum: "$ExpiringInAWeek" }
    }
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0 }}
 ]);
```

Consider also to make two simple requests:

```
var numberOfSubscriptionExpiringToday = db.collection.count(
   { "ExpirationDate": { $gte: today, $lt: tomorrow }}
);

var numberOfSubscriptionExpiringWithInAWeek = db.collection.count(
   { "ExpirationDate": { $gte: tomorrow , $lt: weekAfterToday }}
);
```